# Asp.net and mySQL db: issue MySQLMembership always returning null from GetUser method

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a problem that all of Sudden have started. The website used to work but from one day toanother user cant login, they get ligger out directly. Why is MySQLMembership always returning null from GetUser method. This SI What i thing IT is!

I Even tried a different webhost but same issue. 
I rum asp.net 3.5

I tried to find a solarium for 3 days now, and i am really stuck so I am reaching out an hand here!

Comment: how should we know? You've provided absolutely NOTHING useful, like actual code... we're not psychic. we can't read your mind or view your screen through your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorr but i am not coder. here is some part of the web.config file. The webhost downgraded us to mySQL 5 then it works, but they said they will sooon upgrade us again so we need to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

`<system.web>
    <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="xxxAB" validation="SHA1" validationKey="xxx77F95A" />
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" cookieTimeout="2000" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
    <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="mysqlConnString" applicationName="Klockreparationer" type="Andri.Web.MySqlRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="mysqlConnString" applicationName="Klockreparationer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" name="MySqlMembershipProvider" encryptionKey="xx" type="Andri.Web.MySqlMembershipProvider" />`